# If $a_n\sim b_n$ and $b_n\to 0$, then $a_n\to 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be two sequences with
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1,
$$
which one usually writes as $a_n\sim b_n$. Let $b_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. My question is, if then $a_n\to 0$, too.

Comment: From the limit condition, eventually $|a_n|\le2|b_n|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: assume the opposite. If $a_n\to 0$ were wrong, then we would have $|a_n|>\varepsilon$ for arbitrarily large $n$. 
However, since $b_n\to 0$, what would that tell us about $|\frac{a_n}{b_n}|$?

Comment: Then $\left\lvert\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right\rvert$ would diverge, but by assumption it is $\left\lvert\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right\rvert\to 1$. Right?

Comment: But it's actually not true, is it?

Comment: @servabat What exactly do you think is wrong here?

Comment: @math12 You are correct. The conclusion contradicts one of your assumptions. You know that $a_n\sim b_n$ and that $b_n\to0$, so the only assumption that could possibly be false is $a_n\not\to0$. Therefore, $a_n\to0$.

Comment: Well, I just remember some exceptions when the limit was 0 (it was working only for a limit different from 0) but I'm probably confused then

Answer (score 6):

We have $a_n\sim b_n$ so there's a sequence $(\epsilon_n)$ convergent to $0$ such that

$$a_n=(1+\epsilon_n)b_n$$
and the result follows easily.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_n}{b_n}\cdot b_n\right)=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right)\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\right)=1\cdot0=0$.